# Joomla 1.5 jdoc include type head works only on homepage?

Tags: joomla

I have a problem withjdoc include head. On any other page than Home, the `<jdoc:include type="head" />` result is not complete, it does not include jQuery library etc. but only the title and favicon. Any idea how could I keep the JS libraries and all from jdoc head on all pages, not just the homepage ? I don't know why they get loaded on home but not on login for example, or search...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default header in Joomla doesn't contain jQuery... It loads Mootools.

If you need to load jQuery you have to use a plugin [like this one](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/scripts/12995).